# Could the European Union (or an element of it) be described as a government?

Tags: european-union, terminology

Could the European Union (or an element of it) be described as a government?

The [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government) of government seems quite broad:

> A government is the system or group of people governing an organized
>   community, often a state.

Comment: The EU has a legislative branch (EU Parliament) and an executive branch (EU Commision). I would call both of those elements of a government.

Comment: Thank you. So it meets the definition of a government?

Comment: I am not sure it could be described as much of anything else.

Comment: and with europol and the planned pan-EU army they have police and soon armed forces as well (and technically they already have armed forces in the various combined units made up of troops from various countries, but those aren't officially under direct EU control but rather shared control of the countries providing those troops).

Comment: Technically, all member states of EU could be called its elements, and since every member state has its own government, there is plenty of governments to go around. On other hand, I would hesitate to call EU a government, since a government in my perception is usually associated with monopoly on violence https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_on_violence across its area, which EU doesn't have.

Comment: The EU directs NATO assets? (Eg. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Atalanta)

Comment: Note: the word "government" [means something different](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38083/does-government-mean-something-different-in-british-and-american-english) in the UK and USA. In the former, it refers *only* to the executive branch. In the latter, it can refer to all 3 branches.

Answer (score 6):

## Could it be described as a government? Yes.

There is a wide variety of constitutional arrangements on Earth. Some have a written constitution, some do not. The EU has a number of attributes of a government, for example the EU parliament. EU documents talk about EU citizenship, and this citizenship gives many rights usually reserved for the citizens of a state. *Only* the EU is allowed to negotiate trade agreements for the member states.

## Could it be described as not a government? Yes.

A government is usually an attribute of a state, and of a **sovereign** state in particular. The EU is not sovereign by itself, it is an union of sovereign states which delegate the exercise of some their sovereign powers to the EU. EU member states are allowed to leave in accordance with *their own* constitutional requirements. Citizens of other member states may be deported from EU states.

## Is there an *official* definition of government? No.

Comment: The EU has all the features of a government and yet in this answer you appear to make an argument that it might _not_ be a government because of the origin of its sovereignty? On what basis is this argument founded? Why is the origin of the sovereignty relevant here? It wields sovereignty. It has a legislature, judiciary and executive. It's a government?

Comment: @Ben, when the governments of two states meet in a structured setting, does that make them a joint government? I think not. The EU is a *very* structured union of states, but arguably it is not a state, and without a state there cannot be a real government.

Comment: The EU is more than intergovernmentalism though. The Commission/Parliament/COM triad is delegated and pooled sovereignty: supranationalism. And there is a state: infact there are 28 of them.

Comment: @Ben, 28 states are not one. Consider: once the UK leaves the EU, UK citizens are no longer EU citizens. If the EU was more like a state, they'd retain the citizenship.

Comment: I guess I dispute your premise governing multiple states breaks the definition of a government. The EU is a government that governs multiple states.

Comment: @o.m. I don't find the citizenship argument convincing.  When Yugoslavia broke up, people ceased to be Yugoslav citizens; when Suriname became independent from the Netherlands people ceased to be Dutch citizens; if Texas were to secede from the US, Scotland from the UK, or (to pick a non-federal example) any given prefecture from Japan, people would cease to be US, UK, or Japanese citizens, yet nobody disputes that Yugoslavia was or the Netherlands, the US, the UK, or Japan is a state.  I don't disagree with the answer, but I think the argument for "not a government" could be stronger.

Comment: @phoog, if Scotland left the UK, would a Scotland-born resident of Wales be deported to back to Scotland? I don't think so.

Comment: @o.m. I don't think so either.  The way this typically works is that people have to choose, and if they don't live in the territory of the nationality they have chosen, they may have to move (as did 1/3 of the population of Suriname) or they may be able to get residence documents.  The example of Czechoslovakia is also instructive.  If Scotland were to become independent, there is no way they would be able to determine people's citizenship simply by place of birth, but that doesn't mean that every UK citizen would continue to be a UK citizen.

Comment: @phoog, UK citizens will not get such a choice as yiou describe it on Brexit. They must apply for citizenship using almost-normal procedures.

Comment: Perhaps that is a useful distinction. Citizenship of the EU is almost entirely controlled by its member states, whereas citizenship of other countries is typically controlled by the higher-level entity.  But then there's [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_nationality_law).

Comment: @phoog, scroll back to my answer. I think the original question cannot properly be answered, because the EU has both characteristics of a government and characteristics of not a government.